# ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when calling DeviceIoControl with IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a task to get VendorId and ProductId of devices mounted as disks. Code looks like that:

```
int main() {
    HANDLE hDevice;
    char cDisk = 'c';   // Get metadata about the C:\ disk

                        // Build the logical drive path and get the drive device handle
    std::wstring logicalDrive = L"\\\\.\\";
    wchar_t drive[3];
    drive[0] = cDisk;
    drive[1] = L':';
    drive[2] = L'\0';
    logicalDrive.append(drive);

    hDevice = CreateFile(
        logicalDrive.c_str(),
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    _tprintf(_T("%s\n"), logicalDrive.c_str());

    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cerr << "CreateFile error #" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    // Now that we have the device handle for the disk, let us get disk's metadata  

    CHANGER_PRODUCT_DATA dg = { 0 };
    DWORD ioctlJnk;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice,
        IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA,
        NULL,
        0,
        &dg,
        sizeof(dg),
        &ioctlJnk,
        NULL)
        )
    {
        std::cerr << "DeviceIoControl error #" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    // Success, now print the device manufacturer's name
    std::cout << dg.VendorId << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
}
```

The trouble is that `DeviceIoControl` function fails and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. It happens with any disk.

What can I do to make this code work? Any other ideas how to get VID & PID through the character of mounted device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like C++ and not C, update your tags.  The C language does not have the `std::` namespace nor the `wstring` type.

Comment: are `DeviceIoControl` or `CreateFile` fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` ? i guess `CreateFile` if you only not on xp run this code

Comment: @RbMm, I run it on Win10 but `DeviceIoControl` falis, not `CreateFile`

Comment: @OldNo7 - interesting, need check this on win10. however how i describe in self answer this ioctl require read access on  file handle

Comment: @RbMm - thanks, I added, but it still not works

Comment: @OldNo7 - yes, i forget that `CreateFile` internal add `SYNCHRONIZE` to `dwDesiredAccess` if we not using `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`. what i wrote is correct for `ZwCreateFile`

Comment: @OldNo7 - and what is error after you add `FILE_GENERIC_READ` ?

Comment: `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED` - because volume device not support this requests

Answer (score 2):

You might need to open the device with sufficient access rights and/or have sufficient privileges to use that I/O control function, but your fundamental problem is that you're using it with the wrong kind of device. The `IOCTL_CHANGER_*` functions only work with changer devices, and these devices have a file name in the form of `\\.\Changer#`.  From the [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx#Changer_Device) documentation on MSDN:

> #### Changer Device
>
> The **IOCTL_CHANGER_*** control codes for DeviceIoControl accept a handle to a changer device. To open a changer device, use a file name of the following form: "\\.\Changerx" where x is a number that indicates which device to open, starting with zero. To open changer device zero in an application that is written in C or C++, use the following file name: "\\\\.\\Changer0".

Note that you're not the first person to make this mistake. [Juan Pablo reported on the MinGW mailing list](http://mingw-users.narkive.com/qZ1QO4kT/how-to-get-the-hdd-serial-number) getting the same error with similar code. Luke Dunstan notes that in that thread fixing the code to use GENERIC_READ changes the failure to ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION.

Finally, I'd also note that the file name you're using `\\.\C:` isn't the name of a physical disk.  It's the name of a volume on a physical disk. There can be multiple volumes on a physical disk and a volume can span multiple physical disks.

Comment: are there any other ways to get VID & PID if `IOCTL_CHANGER_*` doesn't suit?

Comment: @OldNo7 VID and PID are USB concepts so most disks, not being USB drives, wouldn't have them. If you're only interested in the VID and PID of USB drives then I believe you'll need to enumerate all the USB devices and (somehow) figure out which one corresponds to the drive you're interested in. This post shows some of what you need to do: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41cb266c-0a55-48c9-be6c-1306882b44a7/mapping-usb-storage-devices-vid-pid-to-physicaldrive-number-using-device-installation-functions?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 0):

look for `IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA` definintion:

```
#define IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA       CTL_CODE(IOCTL_CHANGER_BASE, 0x0002, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS)
```

note `FILE_READ_ACCESS` so file handle must have `FILE_READ_DATA`, but how you open file ?

```
hDevice = CreateFile(
        logicalDrive.c_str(),
        0,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
```

change to

```
hDevice = CreateFile(
    logicalDrive.c_str(),
    FILE_GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL);
```

after this you already got another error - `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED` because you select incorrect device to request this